# Why doesn't code after a window.open call get executed?

Tags: javascript

I have some very simple javascript code that looks like this:

```
var newWindow = window.open("","");
if (newWindow != null)
{
   newWindow.document.write("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>hi</TITLE></HEAD>");
   newWindow.document.close();
}

document.getElementById('status1').innerHTML = "opened a new window";
```

But for some reason the document.getElementById... part never gets called. Is this expected, or am I doing something wrong? (Yes, status1 is defined)

Comment: That suggests that you get an error message. Have you turned error messages on (IE) or opened the console (Firefox, et.c.) so that you see the error messages?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/WrvDN/ Does an element with ID `status1` exist at the time you execute the code?

Comment: @FelixKling for me in Safari, the popup blocker stops the window opening, so `newWindow` is null and `newWindow.document.write` never gets called. http://jsfiddle.net/WrvDN/1/

Comment: Yes, status1 exists at the time of the innerHTML call. If I put that line before the window.open call it gets executed fine. Additionally, I tried debugging this in firebug (in ff) but when it hits the window.open line it kills the firebug session.

Comment: Still, your code works perfectly fine in Safari. Even with my original fiddle, the `document.getElementById` line is exectued. Of course if the window was not opened (blocked), the code inside the `if` statement is not executed. You said *"the document.getElementById... part never gets called"* which is not true, it gets called. So what is your problem now?

Comment: I was getting an error, a different (unrelated) variable was not defined. Thanks guys for the great jsfiddle resource, that surely will come in handy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Guffa says, look for an error message. `newWindow.document` is possibly null or undefined, since it may take longer to open the window than to execute `newWindow != null`.